# intermittent error while browsing on chrome DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET

Tags: networking, firefox, google-chrome, dns, 15.10

On ubuntu 15.10 while browsing with firefox or chrome i randomly get this error and then i have no internet unless i reconnect to the wifi (or reboot)

the error > DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET

Does anyone has any idea of how to properly troubleshoot this? I found a few articles but couldnt fix it still, so Its driving me crazy and desperated. help please

- [this resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32045682/dns-probe-finished-bad-config-error?rq=1) didnt work for me
- i have another laptop at home with lubuntu and that one is fine.

Comment: I too have the similar problem for so long. What did you get in `journalctl` logs when the problem happens?

Comment: this is what i get when i run journalctl http://pastebin.com/RSzmB5U9

Comment: You should either paste the entire log or use the end `-e` flag `journalctl -e` **when it happens**

Comment: sorry, this is the output of journalctl -e while the error appears http://pastebin.com/dpKGXNfh 

im trying to check with half duplex and if there is proper compatibility with the NIC on 15.10

Comment: a friend cleared it out:
lspci -v says i have a realtek rtl8723be so i just need to 

* create  /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf file and edit it to this line:

* options rtl8723be fwlps=0

Comment: Could you ask him to answer this in detail? Here's my `lspci -v`:  http://pastebin.com/NwmwQy12

Comment: @reversiblean, your wifi driver in use is iwlwifi, try this:

(1) echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a    /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf

(2) and set your wifi router to WPA2-AES<br/>

(3) reboot and let me know

Comment: My WPA was set to auto. I just changed it to **WPA2-AES**. Let's see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

1 # `lspci -v` to check your network card / driver in use

2 # `echo options rtl8723be fwlps=0 | tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf`

3 - change router to **WPA2-AES**